# In Objective-C under MRC if an object gets de-alloced do objects it created get de-allocated as well?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

This may look like a dup of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10842829/will-an-associated-object-be-released-automatically), but I don't think that answers my question as it is about associated objects, not objects that were created by and whose only pointer resides within an object.

Let's say I had this example in MRC mode.

```
// In h file
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController {
   NSObject* myNsObject;
}

// In m file
-(void) viewDidLoad() {
   myNsObject = [[NSObject alloc] init];  // I'm never going to release myNsObject
}
```

I'm smart enough to release myViewController correctly.  It's reference count goes to zero and it is de-allocated.  But I never released myNsObject, so it had been hanging around with a reference count of 1.  So would a release, and therefore de-alloc, automatically get done on myNsObject?  Or would myNsObject get leaked in that case?

Comment: No, this does not look like a dupe of that other question at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper memory management here is to release `myNsObject` in the `dealloc` method of the view controller:

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [myNsObject release];

    [super dealloc];
}
```

If you create something then you are responsible for releasing it (under MRC).

Failure to do this results in memory leaks.